# Discord PHP Create Invite link From Channel ID

Tags: php, discord

I am developing a discord bot with php. I want to create invite link via [DiscordPHP](https://github.com/discord-php/DiscordPHP) package.

Here what I write

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Discord\Discord;
$discord = new Discord([
    'token' => 'MY_TOKKEN',
]);
$discord->on('ready', function ($discord) {
    echo "Bot is ready!", PHP_EOL;
    $discord->on('message', function ($message, $discord) {
        $channel = $message->channel;
        $channel->createInvite([
            'max_age' => 60,
            'max_uses' => 5,
        ])->done(function (Invite $invite) {
            echo $invite->code;
        });
    });
});
$discord->run();
```

From `echo $invite->code;` I didn't getting any response string which I acn use to share.

Comment: Please guide me if I am in wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know discord lib , but you can debug by make `var_dump($invite)` and check result if you getting anything
My update
run this

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Discord\Discord;
$discord = new Discord([
    "token" => "your token",
]);
$discord->on('ready', function ($discord) {
    echo "Bot is ready!", PHP_EOL;
    $discord->on('message', function ($message, $discord) {
        $channel = $message->channel;
        $channel->createInvite([
            'max_age' => 60,
            'max_uses' => 5,
        ])->done(function (Invite $invite) {
            echo $invite->code;
        });
    });
}); $discord->run();
```

and check permissions on your discord that bot allowed to make invite

Comment: I am using it like `echo var_dump($invite);`

Comment: what result you getting ? null ? or empty string ?

Comment: I got nothing.
Just few commands I get
`DiscordPHP.DEBUG: REQ POST channels/905128300005961750/invites successful [] []`

Comment: Okay here what  see in docs, will update answer

Comment: Trying to understand what you doing , you trying to create event ?

Comment: is not nothing it shows you that you getting two empty arrays , let me think

Comment: Okay , you make miss type on  $channel = $message->channel; change to  $channel = $message->channel();

Comment: `Call to undefined method Discord\Parts\Channel\Message::channel()`

Comment: just update my answer if it won't work then you need get into docs

Comment: let me know what you get from response

Comment: `Call to undefined method Discord\Parts\Channel\Message::channel()` This one

Comment: sorry,  $message->channels->get('id', '1234'); or  $message->channel->get('id', '1234');

Comment: now should work

Comment: With '$channel = $message->channels->get('id', '233');' I get `Call to a member function get() on null`

Comment: And with `$channel = $message->channel->get('id', '12');`
I got `Call to undefined method Discord\Parts\Channel\Channel::get()`

Comment: did you With '$channel = $message->channels->get('id', '233');' I get Call to a member function get() on null  , means you did not provide parameters correct

Comment: Now I got `BUCKET getgateway/bot queued REQ GET gateway/bot [] []` this

Comment: here what i got "skotow","avatar":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png?size=1024","discriminator":"1254","bot":null,"system":null,"mfa_enabled":null,"locale":null,"verified":false,"email":"
freelancersome@gmail.com","flags":null,"premium_type":null,"public_flags":null}} []
[2021-11-03T00:10:52.149022+01:00] DiscordPHP.INFO: did not parse private channels [] []
[2021-11-03T00:10:52.155674+01:00] DiscordPHP.INFO: stored guilds {"count":1,"unavailable":0} []
[2021-11-03T00:10:52.155921+01:00] DiscordPHP.INFO: client is ready [] []
Bot is ready!

Comment: but i got those errors

Comment: Do you providing correct token ?? you need one that not for mobile view , you need the first one that shows in your console on  discord here is video where get your discord Bearer token https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEgFvgg7ZPI

Comment: Didn't Work that method for me

Comment: I did place exactly your code to my editor and run with my token and all that worked please check in your discord permissions ,